# How to access industryVertical dimension in Google Analytics?

Tags: r, windows, api, google-analytics

There is a feature in GA that let's users compare their company to industry benchmarks. This feature is in the Audience section of GA and should be denoted as industryVertical. It is possible to download some of this data through GA UI, however I want to access it through the GA API. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is another way to access it for several accounts at once? Preferably through googleAnalyticsR (v4).

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This data is not available in the v4 API, unfortunately.

Source - the [v4 API dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)